# ZipArchiveInputStream created from InputStream, unable to read the content

Tags: java, apache, apache-commons, apache-commons-compress

Working Code :

```
InputStream is  = zipFile.getInputStream(zipArchiveEntry);
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(zis));
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

String line;
while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
      System.out.println(line);
}
```

Not Working Code

```
    InputStream is  = zipFile.getInputStream(zipArchiveEntry);

    ZipArchiveInputStream zis = new ZipArchiveInputStream(is);
    if(zis.canReadEntryData(zipArchiveEntry)) {
            // Start
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(zis));
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line;
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println(line);
        } 
}
```

Idea is rather than reading from InputStream, i try to create ZipArchiveInputStream from InputStream, so that I can utilize canReadEntryData() method. canReadEntryData() works completely fine. It returns true for normal files, but I am not able to read content from ZipArchiveInputStream .

Please help. Kindly point where am I going wrong.

Comment: Getting any error? If error means post the stacktrace

Comment: What is a `ZipArchiveInputStream`? DYM [`ZipInputStream`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/zip/ZipInputStream.html)?  For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: @SAN3 No Error . Just that the System.out.println doesn't print anything :(

Comment: @AndrewThompson ZipArchiveInputStream is a class from apache commons compress package to read Zip Files

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**[`ZipArchiveInputStream`](http://commons.apache.org/compress/apidocs/org/apache/commons/compress/archivers/zip/ZipArchiveInputStream.html) vs [`ZipFile`](http://commons.apache.org/compress/apidocs/org/apache/commons/compress/archivers/zip/ZipFile.html)**

It appears that `ZipArchiveInputStream` has some limitations as stated by the official [documentation](http://commons.apache.org/compress/zip.html):

> ZIP archives store a archive entries in sequence and contain a
>   registry of all entries at the very end of the archive. It is
>   acceptable for an archive to contain several entries of the same name
>   and have the registry (called the central directory) decide which
>   entry is actually to be used (if any).
>
> In addition the ZIP format stores certain information only inside the
>   central directory but not together with the entry itself, this is:
>
> - internal and external attributes
> - different or additional extra fields
>
> This means the ZIP format cannot really be parsed correctly while
>   reading a non-seekable stream, which is what `ZipArchiveInputStream`
>   is forced to do. As a result `ZipArchiveInputStream`
>
> - may return entries that are not part of the central directory at all and shouldn't be considered part of the archive.
> - may return several entries with the same name.
> - will not return internal or external attributes.
> - may return incomplete extra field data.
>
> `ZipArchiveInputStream` shares these limitations with
>   `java.util.zip.ZipInputStream`.
>
> `ZipFile` is able to read the central directory first and provide
>   correct and complete information on any ZIP archive.
>
> ZIP archives know a feature called the data descriptor which is a way
>   to store an entry's length after the entry's data. This can only work
>   reliably if the size information can be taken from the central
>   directory or the data itself can signal it is complete, which is true
>   for data that is compressed using the DEFLATED compression algorithm.
>
> `ZipFile` has access to the central directory and can extract entries
>   using the data descriptor reliably. The same is true for
>   `ZipArchiveInputStream` as long as the entry is DEFLATED. For STORED
>   entries `ZipArchiveInputStream` can try to read ahead until it finds
>   the next entry, but this approach is not safe and has to be enabled by
>   a constructor argument explicitly.

Conclusion:

> If possible, you should always prefer `ZipFile` over `ZipArchiveInputStream`.

I believe, by `ZipFile` the above sentence means the use of `InputStream` created using a `ZipFile`:

`InputStream is  = zipFile.getInputStream(zipArchiveEntry);`

Answer (score 1):

I think this code sample will help you to read the Zip using commons compress

```
            ZipFile zipFile = new ZipFile("C:\\test.zip");
            byte[] buf = new byte[65536];
            Enumeration<?> entries = zipFile.getEntries();
            while (entries.hasMoreElements()) {
                ZipArchiveEntry zipArchiveEntry = (ZipArchiveEntry) entries.nextElement();
                int n;
                InputStream is = zipFile.getInputStream(zipArchiveEntry);
                ZipArchiveInputStream zis = new ZipArchiveInputStream(is);
                if (zis.canReadEntryData(zipArchiveEntry)) {
                    while ((n = is.read(buf)) != -1) {
                        if (n > 0) {
                            System.out.println(new String(buf));
                        }
                    }
                }
                zis.close();
            }
```